# Wrong name in Family Sharing?

Tags: ios, accounts, family-sharing

When reviewing my family within Family Sharing, I discovered that the wrong name was showing for my account.   This was not the Apple ID name, or any information from my apple account.

A google search for resolving this issue when discovered on family sharing was *not* helpful.

Where does the name shown for my account in Family Sharing come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS Family Sharing uses Settings->Contacts->My Info

This allows you to choose which of your contacts has information about yourself, such as your name.

Alternatively, this is accessible at the top of the "Contacts" app as "My Card."

I believe one of my kids had edited this 'My Info/My Card' contact.  Family sharing is using this to display whatever nickname I prefer on this particular device.   Perhaps if the contact was named "me" then I'd see "Me."

Comment: I love you for this. Even my automations were working incorrectly.